# What do you assert in a test that causes navigation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects

I'm looking for methods to assert that an action caused the expected navigation. For example, after logging out, I want to assert that I'm back at the login page.

At first I did an assert on the (relative) URL, but it didn't feel right. As a second attempt, I try to access an element that should be on the page.

```cs
var loginPage = new LoginPage(this.Driver)
    .LogIn()
    .LogOut();

var assert = loginPage.LoginButton.ToString();
```

If it doesn't throw, then it can be said with reasonable certainty that the test is successful.

Are there any other methods that you've had success with?

Comment: are you using a framewor such as JUnit or TestNG In your project or are you relying on Java asserts?

Comment: @ECiurleo I'm using xUnit.net, it's a C# project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assert an expected element is present on the returned page using NUnit eg

```
        Assert.AreEqual(loginPage.LoginButton.ToString(), "Login");
```

Common elements to use would be;

- an ID (unique element on the page)
- Page Title
- Contextual (like the example above).

Avoid using things like the URL which often contain things like session information (and therefore subject to change)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to assert a text in the page you are navigating to.

You can also assert page/window title.

Another way to assert whether an image or an element specific to that page is present or not.

Comment: The window title sounds good. More stable than an URL, and easier than choosing an element for each page.